# Serial communication between pc and arduino via RS232 using c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, arduino, serial-communication

I am trying to communicate with my arduino duemilanove via an RS232 cord. I simply want to be able to send a byte (or char) to my arduino from a desktop application.  The Arduino is plugging into USB COM5 on my computer.  I have the RS232 plugged into COM1, and then I have pins 2 3 and 5 on the other end of the RS232 connected to arduino pins TX, RX, and GND, respectively.

I found a serial comm class for c++ at the following link:

http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows

I have added the .h and .cpp files from the above example as Serial.h and Serial.cpp (i think the example uses SerialClass.h and SerialClass.cpp, I just changes the names).

---

On my arduino, I have the following code running:

```
// ARDUINO
char incomingByte = 0;

void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

        // send data only when you receive data:
        if (Serial.available() > 0) {
                // read the incoming byte:
                incomingByte = Serial.read();

                // say what you got:
                Serial.print("I received: ");
                Serial.println(incomingByte, HEX);
        }
}
```

---

And my c++ program is the following:

```
// C++
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Serial.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    Serial port("COM1");

    char* msg = "Hello Arduino!";
    int msgLen = strlen(msg);
    bool writeSuccess = port.WriteData(msg, msgLen);

    cout << "\n\n";
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

---

When I use the Arduino's serial port viewer to see what is bring printed, I'm getting very strange values that don't match what I'm sending (as far as I can tell).

When I send "Hello Arduino!", the arduino prints the following:

```
I received: FFFFFFAB
I received: 3A
I received: 3A
I received: A
I received: FFFFFFFA
I received: FFFFFFEB
I received: 6D
I received: 37
I received: 15
I received: 2D
I received: 23
I received: 21
I received: FFFFFFBD
I received: 0
```

This does not appear to be the correct hex for "Hello Arduino!", but I have no idea why it's not correct.  Does anyone have any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set COM1 into 9600 speed as well? Are stop/parity bits the same as well?

Comment: @Slava Yep and yep http://i.imgur.com/CIt2Kog.png

Comment: It is operating system specific.

Comment: Suggest to change you C++ code ...
[See this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/992/Serial-library-for-C).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino used TTL logic for Serial connection. It expects values at 0 and 5V. RS232 used a different voltage -V to +V. You may need a converter.

Comment: But Arduino has a pull_up and pull_down resistor for this reason ,  [see this](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins)

Answer (score 1):

Ehm... No! pull up and pull down are not for this reason..

- TTL = low: 0V, high: 5V
- RS232 = low: +3:+15V, high: -3:-15V

Consequently.. You need a voltage converter (and inverter), like David Skogan correctly pointed out.

Examples:

1. Using discrete components (has automatic echo feature, i.e. on the PC you will see the data you send): http://project.irone.org/simple-rs232-to-ttl-level-converter.html or http://circuit-diagram.hqew.net/Simple-TTL$2dRS232-Level-Converter-Using-Transistor_2757.html
2. Common circuit with a MAX232 (or equivalent) and four capacitors
3. Instead of using a USB-RS232 converter use a USB-UART one, using for instance a FT232 or something like that. This does not need any interface

Or.. simply use the USB port on the Arduino, which already has a FT232 on it.

Personal comment: i'd avoid solution 1...